# Convert coursera courses to ECTs

Tags: working-time, mooc

TL:DR version: I took some Coursera courses, I want to know how many credits they are worth by the institution backing it up (as well as how many credits a semester they offer, preferably, in the semester they offer that course).

Full version: I know title may be a little confusing so I will clarify.
I am applying for a Master's Degree program, and the pre-requisites include mathematical knowledge. I am an MD, so math is not a big part of my undergraduate program, however I work as a developer, and there I apply mathematical principles. For this course I need to prove my knowledge on the subjects of Probability and Statistics, Linear Algebra and Calculus so I contacted the institution and they told me I could study those subjects online via Coursera. I chose my courses and I am currently studying them.

However application period has already started, and as part of pre-requisites I gotta fill a form, and some fields are about ECTs in the already mentioned subjects. I asked the institution via email how would I fill these, and they told me I can specify the course duration (in hours) and also how many credits (hours) a semester is offered in that institution, in order for them to know how many credits (ECTs) are they worth.

In this situacion, how could I know could I know how many credits a course is worth in the institution that backs up that course in Coursera? and how could I know how many credits a semester it is worth?

Specific courses are (feel free to suggest better alternatives, since I don't have to complete them due the deadline, rather I have to compromise to take them):

Linear Algebra (Matrix algebra): https://www.coursera.org/learn/matrix-algebra-engineers

The three courses in this program (calculus, linear algebra): https://www.coursera.org/learn/linear-algebra-machine-learning

Probability and Statistics: https://www.coursera.org/learn/probability-statistics?

Comment: 1 ECTS credit nominally corresponds to 25-30 hours of work (depending on the country). 1 semester usually consists of 30 credits, again this might depend on the country. Since the coursera courses list the approximate time needed, you should be able to do the calculation that way.

Comment: @AzorAhai Are you sure, you are talking about ECTS and not some different credits though? There is quite some variance for a system that was supposed to make things comparable europe-wide, but 25 hours per credit seems to be the absolute lower bound: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Credit_Transfer_and_Accumulation_System)

Comment: @mlk You know, I got ECTS and CEUs confused lol, nevermind me

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind responses. The instructions give by this institution's representative were clear. I have to write into the form how much time I spent in the course (measured by the course itself, so no problem), and also how much credits/hours that school has per semester, in order for them to calculate equivalence. My question is how could I could gather this last fact.

Answer (score 1):

Usually European universities have a course schedule that shows also the European credits adjusted. You could access the website of the university that offers the course, look for the class and see in the syllabus/course content how many credits it is. Usually this is not shown in application pages but rather in tabs such as “class search” or something similar